# LibGDX scissors does not work

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, clipping

I want to clip a certain part of the screen, thus everything which lays outside is not drawn.
My code looks like this:

```
public void draw(Camera camera, ShapeRenderer renderer){
        Rectangle scissors = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle clipBounds = new Rectangle(pos.x, pos.y, pos.x+width, pos.y+height);
        ScissorStack.calculateScissors(camera, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), new Matrix4(), clipBounds, scissors);
        renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);
        for(Block[] row : blocks){
            for(Block block : row)
                block.draw(renderer);// draw some rects
        }
        ScissorStack.popScissors();

        renderer.end();
    }
```

But this code has no effect, i.e. shapes that lay outside clipBounds are drawn, too.
What's wrong with my code?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendering doesn't happen until `renderer.end()` so put that inside your `ScissorStack`.